# How to re-open something after used `JQuery.remove()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a free template for my app and with this template there is a button to "hide" list like this:
[image]

*the little x button*

And the executed code is the following one:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-link', function () {
   var $BOX_PANEL = $(this).closest('.x_panel');
   $BOX_PANEL.remove();
});
```

Now I'm trying to add a button to re-open this list but here comes the struggle I can't find a way to do that. I checked the documentation of [JQuery remove()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_remove.asp) and there is not JQuery open()...

Do you guy have an idea ?

[EDIT] maybe the HTML would be great so :

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Machines</h2>
               <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                  <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                  <li class="dropdwon">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"></ul>
                  </li>
                  {{#if isNotHome}}<li><a class="backLocalHostDocker"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>{{/if}}
                  <li><a class="close-link" id="closeList"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a></li>
              </ul>
           <div class="clearfix"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="x_content">
             <br />
             <ul class="container"></ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*I just cleaned the code to just display the structure*

Comment: why not use `hide` instead of `remove`. Then you can use `show` to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case do not `remove()` which eliminates the element from DOM.

Just use

```
$BOX_PANEL.hide();
```

Then whenever you feel like showing it back, use

```
$BOX_PANEL.show();
```

Comment: Arrr why I didn't look in this way, of course I should use that ! I was stuck in "remove, open" because of the template code... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Use jQuery detach()

The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

[jQuery detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery toggle()` function to `Show/Hide` Tags

**Example :**

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-link', function () {
    $('.x_panel').toggle();
});
```

Now, you can `show/hide` your `.x_panel` block by clicking `.close-link`

> Here is the details about [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.